# Querying the dom for an angularjs object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a page that has a grid of html. For each object, I have added an `ng-style` with an ID.

In my controller, I need to be able to set the styles dependent upon an object name from a data call.

example `"sD3","dD3"`

```
<div id="sD3" data-ng-style="sD3" class="roundabout-rowDcol3"></div>
<div id="dD3" data-ng-style="dD3" class="grid-data-rowDcol3"></div>
```

Other than using a very large switch in my controller, is there another way I can grab the object and set the styles?

Something like this:

```
object = {"background-color": style.backgroundColor, color": style.color,};
```

Comment: Why not create a `.css` class for every object type (*in its own .css file*) and assign the corresponding value using [ngClass](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass)?

Comment: I just want to **strongly** encourage you to consider @Igor comment - that is the "Angular way" to do things.  Doing it other ways is more work, harder to maintain, and not the "Angular" way.

Answer (score 1):

Use a property accessor on `$scope`.

For:

```
<div id="sD3" data-ng-style="sD3" class="roundabout-rowDcol3"></div>
```

Use:

```
var id = "sD3";

$scope[id] = {"background-color": style.backgroundColor, "color": style.color,};
```

Comment: Wow, thanks that's what is was needing... looks like i need a bit more angular learning..